# Submit the task in Google Earth Engine Python client

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, tasks

I use the GEE Python client to perform image fusion. There are two nested for loops, in the end, I use the `ee.batch.export.toDrive` method to create the task. However, each task consumes a significant amount of time and user memory. So I want to submit the task without automatic execution to control the running tasks number. I tried the `task.state = 'READY'`, but I could not find the task, there was also no 'run' button. How can I solve this problem?

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
image=preds.rename(predNames).multiply(10000).toInt16(),
description= export_description,
folder = folder.getInfo(),
region = ee.Image(prediction.get(0)).geometry(),
scale = 30)\

task.state = 'READY'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear, but I think what you're asking is how to start a task.
You do that with task.start().

From the built-in python documentation:

```
>>> import ee
>>> help(ee.batch.Task)

class Task(builtins.object)
 |  Task(task_id, task_type, state, config=None, name=None)
 |  ...
 |  start(self)
 |      Starts the task. No-op for started tasks.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you suggesting to use ee.batch.Task to create tasks instead of using ee.batch.export.toDrive() to create tasks?

Comment: Not exactly.  `ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive()` returns a `Task`, that you have to `start()`.  The docs for ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive() say: "Returns: An unstarted Task that exports the table"